# How to store timestamp data on spark using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a timeseries data reading from database into Spark.

Which DataType could I use in scale to store Date and Timestamp?

Comment: you can use java.sql.Timestamp

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with TimestampType?

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/DataTypes.html#TimestampType

Comment: thumbs up for sharing the Spark DataType link :)